# Pandas - groupby ID and select the item purchased after the input one

Tags: python, pandas

I’ve got a dataframe like this one:

```js
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [123214, 123214, 321455, 321455, 234325, 234325, 234325, 234325, 132134, 132134, 132134],
        "DATETIME": ["2020-05-28", "2020-06-12", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-11", "2020-02-06", "2020-07-24", "2020-10-14", "2020-03-04", "2020-09-11", "2020-10-17"],
        "CATEGORY": ["computer technology", "early childhood", "early childhood", "shoes and bags", "early childhood", "garden and gardening", "musical instruments", "handmade products", "musical instruments", "early childhood", "beauty"]})
```

I’d like to:

- Group by ID
- Where CATEGORY == “early childhood” (input), select the next item bought (next row)

The result should be:

```
321455  "2020-01-10"    "shoes and bags"
234325  "2020-02-06"    "garden and gardening"
132134  "2020-10-17"    "beauty"
```

The shift function for Pandas is what I need but I can’t make it work while grouping.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create mask with test `CATEGORY` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html), replace first missing values to `False` and pass to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#if necessary convert to datetimes and sorting
#df['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'])
#df = df.sort_values(['ID','DATETIME'])


mask = df['CATEGORY'].eq('early childhood').groupby(df['ID']).shift(fill_value=False)
df = df[mask]
print (df)
        ID    DATETIME              CATEGORY
3   321455  2020-01-10        shoes and bags
5   234325  2020-02-06  garden and gardening
10  132134  2020-10-17                beauty
```